# Are trailing whitespaces important in Troff manual files?

Tags: troff

I couldn't find a specification of the troff file format. Does the removal of trailing whitespaces have an effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [groff manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/manual/html_node/Filling-and-Adjusting.html) chapter 5 says, for reading normal text:

> Extra spaces between words are preserved, but spaces at the end of lines are ignored.

(There are some exceptions such as when defining strings with `.ds`).
You can experiment yourself:

```
echo -e 'a      b    \nc d' | nroff -man | cat -vet
a      b c d$
$
```